# Using URL in parameter description CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there anyway to use the URL (Clickable string) in parameter description of CLoudFormation, as a tool-tip for user I want to user the link, so user can simply click on it and not copy and paste the URL string.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what do you mean? Where would you use that url?

Comment: I mentioned where in my title, but I updated the question.

Comment: Sadly, there is no such a way.